# Center an object tag in a div

Tags: html, css

How can I center object content within a div?

```
.parent{
background-color:yellow;
}

.ob{
margin: 0 auto;
}
</style>

<div class="parent">
<object width="400" height="400" class="ob" data="helloworld.swf">
</object>
</div>
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6):

An `object` element has inline style by default, and `margin: auto` applies to block-level elements only.

Add this style:

```
.ob {
  display: block;
}
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/s6dobn59/)

Answer (score 1):

Or this since the `object` is an inline element.

```
.parent{
text-align: center;
}
```

If you want to get modern.

```
.parent{
    background-color:yellow;
    display: flex;
    justify-content:center
}
```